# ASP .NET page name "alias"

Tags: asp.net

I have a web of which I have two versions: one in spanish and one in english. They are located in different servers and different domains. So they actually behave as two different websites.

I only have one ASP .NET project, and depending on the domain, I show all texts in spanish or in english. That's working right.

I developed it first in spanish, so my page names are written in spanish, like "Buscar.aspx" ("Buscar" means "Search").

I would like to translate also the page's name, so that in browser's address bar, it would appear the english names. For instance, for my page "Buscar.aspx" I would like to appear "Search.aspx" in the address bar.

So my question is: is there any way to declare some kind of "alias" (or some other mechanism), so that I can process requests to "Buscar.aspx" and "Search.aspx" through one single ASP .NET page, but still appearing in the address bar as two different addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[URL Rewriting](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/)**

You could rewrite `Search.aspx` to `Buscar.aspx`

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Search">
      <match url="^Search.aspx" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Buscar.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

These rules could then be put in your English web.config file

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was very helpful. To make it perfect, I will research on how to make this section conditional to the domain, so that I don't have to mantain two different web.config files. I would like to avoid copying one file to the wrong domain by accident.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at routing. You can find some documentation here: [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#routes)

Routing means that you can specify a path that maps to a certain ASPX. If you switch the routing configuration based on your language setting you have what you need :)

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. Besides my question, in this document I've found some ideas to improve some other aspects of my web.